Permanent residency in Germany
I came to Germany to work as a programmer and was granted a residence permit under § 19c Abs. 2 AufenthG, which I held for 20 months. Then, I converted my residence permit to an EU Blue Card under § 18g Abs. 1 Satz 1 AufenthG five months ago. My question is: When am I eligible to apply for permanent residency?
Is the previous period (20 months) counted towards the duration required for obtaining permanent residency under the Blue Card law, which is 27 months? Or does the 27-month period start from the time I received my Blue Card only?


Is the previous period (20 months) counted towards the duration required for obtaining permanent residency under the Blue Card law, which is 27 months? Or does the 27-month period start from the time I received my Blue Card only?

I believe it's the latter but the law is a bit murky. The law (§ 18c AufenthG explicitly requires 3 years under a permit issued based on §§ 18a, 18b, 18d or § 18g (which is not the case of your permit). This is relevant to you because the 27 months delay for Blue Card holder is defined later in the same article, as an exception to this general rule. This seems to rule out people in your position as you held a residence permit under a different part of the law, namely § 19c.
Now, for Blue card holders this 3-year requirement is reduced to “holding a job under § 18g for 27 months”. This does create some ambiguity as the reference to the basis for the permit is gone, instead the requirement is apparently about the job itself. With a permit under § 19c you do not have a prima facie case to benefit for this reduced requirement but if the job did meet the requirements (minimum qualification, salary threshold) all along, maybe there is a case to be made?
